# Selecting variables alternately in python

Tags: python, flask

a question about python. I have a script that runs on the server, it processes incoming requests, there is a piece of code with variables in the script, I need to make sure that these variables are called in turn. That is, now I'm doing it using the random module like this:

```
Varibale1 = "sometext";
Variable2 = "sometext";
Varibale3 = "sometext";

variable_list = [Varibale1, Varibale2, Varibale3]
variable_work = random.choice(variable_list)
```

Then the variable variable_work performs the necessary work. My question is not to make a random choice of a variable, but a choice in turn, that is:

- a request came to the server --> variable1 is working,
- a second request came to the server --> variable2 is working,
- a third request came --> variable3 is working,
- a fourth request came --> variable1 is working, and so on...

Comment: ANY TIME you have variables called `xxx1` and `xxx2` and `xxx3`, you need to replace that set with a list.  What you're talking about requires a "session".  You'd store the current place in the list in the session dict, and fetch it with the next request.

Comment: You could use Redis, which is an in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache, and message broker. In this case, you'll be using it as a cache. You will store the number, index, in the Redis cache. And for every request, you'll fetch it, increment it (if incrementing exceeds or is equal to the length of the array, then reset to 0) and then use it. This is the only approach that would work for concurrent requests on a server.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter, and access the index of that counter `%` the length of the list:

```
>>> variable_list = ["sometext1", "sometext2", "sometext3"]
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(f"{variable_list[i%len(variable_list)]} is working...")
...
sometext1 is working...
sometext2 is working...
sometext3 is working...
sometext1 is working...
sometext2 is working...
sometext3 is working...
sometext1 is working...
sometext2 is working...
sometext3 is working...
sometext1 is working...
```